# Laravel - views folder getting deleted repeatedly

Tags: laravel, view

Using Laravel Framework 5.5.0.
The `/var/app/current/storage/framework/views` folder is constantly getting deleted.

Has anyone experienced this behavior or know why this would be happening?

*Also worth noting I attempted to circumvent this by setting the immutable flag on the directory but then my frontend stoped working.

Comment: I haven't experienced the folder being deleted, but the files get deleted when the blade template changes as it will parse the blade template to PHP templates again..

Comment: it happens after you running git commands?

Comment: I've seen it happen after running a deployment.  I'm deploying through AWS Elasticbeanstalk CLI. e.g. `eb deploy`. In that case I manually create.  More frequently however it happens while the laravel app is up and running.

Comment: @user857276 do you have a `.gitignore` file inside `views` folder?

Comment: not inside the views folder but I do see one in its parent the storage/framework folder.

Comment: @user857276 that's the problem. Can you show `.gitignore` file from project root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the folder is getting deleted because there is no files tracked by git inside.
Try to add `.gitignore` to the `storage/framework/views` with the following content:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Then remove all gitigore rules for `views` folder in root `.gitignore`.
You should be able to add this file to git index and commit. The problem should be fixed after next deploy.

See: [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: Thanks Andriy! - I implemented your solution and am waiting to see if the folder gets removed while the application is running.